# don't know how to start the program functions

Tags: exit, function

**(Beginner question) It seems I built a house without including a door. As an example, say you have three def blocks:

```
def intro ( ):
  blah
  def middle ( )

def middle ( ):
  blah
  def end ( )

def end ( ):
  blah

intro ( ) #calling function here to start prog causes infinite loop
```

Computer initializes all defs but then exits prog because nothing points back to start. How do you start? If I make def intro the last line in the prog, the thing gets stuck in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Do not write `def` before a function call. Try this instead:

```
def intro():
  print "intro"
  middle()

def middle():
  print "middle"
  end()

def end():
  print "end"

intro()
```